# What does the expression or slang "Bootstrap" means and which expressions contain it in Australian Slang?

Tags: informal-language, australian-english

I have seen "bootstrap" in a few sentences. What does it mean or which expressions contain this word?

> "We ended up in a right bootstrap last night"

> "Bootstrap you horney bugger"

Comment: It means a quite different thing in Australian slang than American, from the sound of those sentences. You should probably narrow the tagging accordingly: pick one.

Comment: I live in Australia, but would be important to know both in Australian and American or even in British English.

Comment: Yes, but it might work better to ask as separate questions: 'What does "bootstrap" mean *in Australian slang*?', for example. When each possible answer has to contain two or three parts, that's not good

Comment: This isn't something I've heard before. Do you have a source for it?

Comment: You are asking for expressions using bootstrap, yet you claim to have seen it in some sentences.  Can you please share them?

Comment: Bootstrap in America is a loop of material attached to the top of a boot allowing one to pull the boot onto ones foot easier.  It also is used in the phrase to pull yourself up by your bootstraps - meaning to work your way out of a mess without anyone else's help - the "American Way".  In computer science, I run into more often as a small piece of computer code that, when run, which allows another more complex piece of code to execute.

Comment: I'm an Australian who grew up in parts of the outback where many of the oddest Australian slang expressions are used without the slightest irony, and I have never heard the expressions above, nor any use of the term 'bootstrap' that can't be construed as 'lift yourself up from no support' (which is also what the computer term means).

Comment: I also live in, and grew up in, Australia, and I have never heard the term "bootstrap" used that way.  Can you link to the source?  Or did you possibly mishear it?

Comment: I am trying to find the original link, I found another link: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bootstrap&defid=8050256 @brendan

Comment: Thanks @RogerOliveira - doesn't that page answer your question then? (though it's British slang, rather than Australian)

Comment: @brendan, yes I found my anwer in that link :)

Comment: Many phrases on urban dictionary are pretty spurious or are just puns.  I'm not saying 'I haven't heard of it so I don't believe it' or anything, but given the upvote/downvote number and ratio on that post I'm a little sceptical.  I'm british and I don't think this would be well understood depending on context.  Saying that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xewe4mlX2tc

Comment: Roger Oliveira, if you are satisfied with the answers given by @brendan's link, do you want to close this question or similar?

Comment: @amblina yes I can close this question.